# how to create spring controller class object in main method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Even though following is inside controller class which can be invoked from web-browser by hitting certain button, but some how I have to invoke doSomething method which is inside StudentController class from main method. I won't be using browser at certain point but still I have to invoke controller classes method from main method.
I won't be able to move doSomething() method in Utility class due to current code complexity.
So I need a solution to invoke doSomething() method by creating StudentController class's object.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/studentController")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private Subject subject;

    public String doSomething()
    {
        return "something";
    }
}   

class Test
{
    //some how I have to invoke doSomething method which is inside StudentController class.
    // I won't be able to move doSomething() method in Utility class due to current code complexity
    // So I need a solution to invoke doSomething() method by creating StudentController class's object.
    // Please check whether following is a correct code.

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //what to do here ? This is spring MVC.
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(StudentController.class);// is this right way?
        StudentController sc = (StudentController)context.getBean("studentController");//what about subject injection
        sc.doSomething(); //is this correct coding ? 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationContext#getBean` - Return the bean instance

`getBean` method available in `BeanFactory` interface which returns the bean instance from spring context.

For Example -

```
StudentController obj = (StudentController) context.getBean("studentcontroller");
```

Dependency will be injected as you configured, conext will automatically resolve dependency and inject to bean class.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you plz elaborate ?

Comment: `StudentController sc = context.getBean(StudentController.class);`

Comment: `<T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType)` is also available

Comment: Sorry I edit by question by putting your above line. Now question is what about `subject` injection ?

Comment: Spring's Dependency Injection functionality is implemented using this BeanFactory interface and its subinterfaces, it will do itself for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want by manually loading application context and get "StudentController" bean from it.
For example:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("<path-to-your-application-context-xml-file>"); //if your application configuration is Java based, you should use another context class
//or
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(<you-configuration-Java-class>);
StudentController controller = (StudentController)applicationContext.getBean("studentController");
controller.doSomething();
```

[Full example](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-creating-a-spring-application.html).
Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using annotation Controller file. I don't have .xml file.